# Can you bind a this value in a generator function

Tags: ecmascript-6

Given that you can't use arrow functions when you need to yield in its body, is it possible to set the `this` value for use in side the body.

I have made myself a database library which extends the "tedious" library that allows me to do something like the following

```
const self = this;
db.exec(function*(connection) {
  let sql = 'SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = @id';
  let request = connection.request(sql);
  request.addParameter('id',db.TYPE.Int, myIdValue);
  let count = yield connection.execSql(function*() {
    let row = yield;
    while(row) {
//process row with somthing like self.processRow(row);
      row=yield;
    }
  });
  if (count > 0) {
    request = connection.request('some more sql');
//etc
  }
  return something;
}).then(something => {
//do some more things if the database access was a success
}).catch(error => {
// deal with any errors.
}) ;
```

I find I am increasingly needing to access the `this` value from the outside and am constantly doing the trick of assigning it to self at the head of the surrounding function.

Is it possible to set the `this` value with something like bind? inside the function* (at multiple levels down!)

Since I have full access to the iterators that I use to implement `db.exec` and `connection.execSql` I can change them if it's possible. to support it.

Comment: You could just bind all of your generator functions all the way down, i.e. `db.exec(function*() { connection.execSql(function*() {}.bind(this)); }.bind(this)); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generator use `this` as normal functions would.

You have few solutions:

- use [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) on generator expression
- pass `this` as first/second argument to generator named `self`
- make `db.exec` take second argument `thisArg`, similar to [array methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

> If a thisArg parameter is provided to forEach(), it will be passed to callback when invoked, for use as its this value.  Otherwise, the value undefined will be passed for use as its this value. The this value ultimately observable by callback is determined according to the usual rules for determining the this seen by a function.

I would suggest going with the last solution.